# Missing library when repacking an Android APK

Tags: java, android, apk

Our organization has developed an Android app which requires a configuration file that is unique for each installation.  So far, we have generated a new configuration file, dropped it into the Android Studio project, and rebuilt the app. After doing some research I concluded that it should be feasible to create a repackaging program.  To this end, I wrote a Windows C# program that:

- Unzips the APK file (using a .net class library)
- Generates a new configuration file
- Replaces the old configuration file
- Deletes the META-INF folder
- Re-zips the APK directory (again using a .Net class)
- Signs the APK using jarsigner from the java jdk
- Tweaks the APK compression with zipalign

The app uses sqlite and has three folders under its lib directory (in the APK), armeabi, armeabi-v7aq, and x86. Each folder contains a version of libsqliteX.so. When I install the original APK on an Android device, I end up with libsqliteX.so in the the directory /data/app/myapp/lib/arm/ and everything works fine. When I install the repackaged app, I get nothing under the /lib folder and the app dies on a "can't find library" error.

I have compared the content of the original and repackaged APK file and they appear the same.  I admit to being a neophyte on Android development but am baffled by the problem.  I have scoured the Internet for a hint but have found nothing useful.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Um, why not use product flavors, so your APK can be built with the configuration file in it through the normal build system?

Comment: I went down the repacking road because it would eliminate the need to have Android Studio installed in order to deploy the app. Instead, all you need is the original app file and the C# program and supporting tools.  The C# program also does a bunch of house keeping and book keeping that I didn't mention because it was not germane to my problem.

Comment: "because it would eliminate the need to have Android Studio installed in order to deploy the app" -- using product flavors does not require Android Studio to be installed. You need the Android SDK and Gradle, though.

Comment: That is certainly an option if I can't resolve my issues.  I still keep hoping for a smaller footprint although that might be misguided. I appreciate the suggestion.

Comment: Oh, I agree, what you are doing should work. I used to do this same sort of thing for my book's APK, albeit using Java instead of C# and without any NDK libraries. I dumped that approach eventually, replacing it with a custom Gradle task. You might want to examine the original APK in a ZIP utility and see what the compression levels are on the NDK binaries. It's possible that they treat those differently (e.g., stored rather than compressed, so a ZIP compression level of 0). If you're not following their pattern, perhaps that screws something up.

Comment: That was a good thought but I looked at both the good and bad APK files.  The .so files are compressed in both or at least they have different original and packed sizes (according to 7-zip).